# use an library available as npm in an angularjs application as dependency

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

How can I use an library available as npm in an angularjs application?

I want to use json-schema-diff-validator library available through NPM, but I'm not able to directly use it as either 'bower component' or directly referencing in my angular controller. Refer to below link for npm library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-diff-validator

Comment: i am using angular JS 1.2.x as the version

Comment: You have to require it and add it to the modules. Use another angular version --- the latest is version 5; if you prefer to use old software, at least use 1.6.x ....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A little hint: You can [edit] your question with this link or over the [edit] button under your question. Please take a look at the "[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)"

Comment: Baao, basically the library i am talking about has node.js code and not javascript code which can be consumed by angular js. so what's the solution in this case. Below is the code snapshot from the library:                                           "use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const assert = require("assert");
const fast_json_patch_1 = require("fast-json-patch");

Comment: and i am getting uncaught refercne at below line:     "use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });